# Regex to swap source and destination in IP access-list

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to swap and source and destination addresses/prefixes of IP access-lists which I take existing ACL entry and create the entry in the opposite direction, as follow:

Input:

> permit ip any host 10.22.122.161
>
> permit ip host 10.11.198.18 any
>
> permit ip host 10.22.122.161 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7
>
> permit ip host 10.22.122.161 host 10.22.122.255
>
> permit ip any host 10.22.122.255
>
> permit ip 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7 host 10.22.122.255
>
> permit ip any 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7
>
> permit ip 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7 any
>
> permit ip any 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15
>
> permit tcp any 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15
>
> permit tcp 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7

Expected output:

> permit ip host 10.22.122.161 any
>
> permit ip any host 10.11.198.18
>
> permit ip 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7 host 10.22.122.161
>
> permit ip host 10.22.122.255 host 10.22.122.161
>
> permit ip host 10.22.122.255 any
>
> permit ip host 10.22.122.255 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7
>
> permit ip 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7 any
>
> permit ip any 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7
>
> permit ip 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15 any
>
> permit tcp 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15 any
>
> permit tcp 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7
>
> permit tcp 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15

but in some cases my function fails to swap source and destination

My codes fails in following test cases:

> permit ip host 10.22.122.161 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7

Following regex fail to match `192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7` with (.*)

> p = re.sub(r'(.*)(\bany\b|\bhost \b\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}) (.*)',r'\1\3 \2',ACELine)

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re

def ChangeACESrcDst(ACELine):
  ReversedACE = str()
  protocols_list = [
    'ip',
    'tcp',
    'udp',
    'gre',
    'icmp'
  ]
  if (bool(re.search(r'(\bpermit\b|\bdeny\b)',ACELine))):
    ACE_ITEMS = ACELine.split()
    if  ACE_ITEMS[1] in protocols_list:
      if len(ACE_ITEMS) == 5:
        if ACE_ITEMS[2] == 'host' or ACE_ITEMS[2] == 'any':
          p = re.sub(r'(.*)(\bany\b|\bhost \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (.*)',r'\1\3 \2',ACELine)
          print(ACELine)
          print(p)
        elif ACE_ITEMS[4] == 'host' or ACE_ITEMS[4] == 'any':  
          p = re.sub(r'(.*) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (\bany\b|\bhost \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',r'\1 \3 \2',ACELine)
          print(ACELine)
          print(p)
      elif len(ACE_ITEMS) == 6: 
        if ACE_ITEMS[2] == 'host' and ACE_ITEMS[4] == 'host':
          p = re.sub(r'(.*) (host \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (host \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',r'\1 \3 \2',ACELine)
          print(ACELine)
          print(p)
        else:
          p = re.sub(r'(.*) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',r'\1 \3 \2',ACELine)
          print(ACELine)
          print(p)
      else:
        print(f'ERROR: ACE items length must be either 5 or 6 : {ACELine}')
    else:
      print(f'ERROR: Protocols not supported : {ACE_ITEMS[1]}') 
      exit() 
    print('\n')

  return ReversedACE


if __name__ == "__main__":
 aces = [
 'permit ip any host 10.22.122.161',
 'permit ip host 10.11.198.18 any',
 'permit ip host 10.22.122.161 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7',
 'permit ip host 10.22.122.161 host 10.22.122.255',
 'permit ip any host 10.22.122.255',
 'permit ip 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7 host 10.22.122.255',
 'permit ip any 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7',
 'permit ip 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7 any',
 'permit ip any 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15',
 'permit tcp any 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15',
 'permit tcp 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7'
 ]
 for ace in aces:
   ace = (ChangeACESrcDst(ace))
```

Input:

> permit ip host 10.22.122.161 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7

Expected output:

> permit ip 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7 host 10.22.122.161

Comment: use `print()` to see which regex is used for this line and then you can see if it uses expected regex and you know which regex to repair.

Comment: I tested code and I see this line uses last regex, not regex which you expected - so you have to check your `if/else`

Comment: @furas, Thanks, you're right, actually the problem was with my `if/else` my problem solved after fixing `if/else` clause. I'll try other answers for more efficient regex though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was with my if/else logic, solving that, I'm getting my expected result, I'm looking for a more efficient way of implementing my funtion

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import re

def ChangeACESrcDst(ACELine):
  ReversedACE = str()
  protocols_list = [
    'ip',
    'tcp',
    'udp',
    'gre',
    'icmp'
  ]
  if (bool(re.search(r'(\bpermit\b|\bdeny\b)',ACELine))):
    ACE_ITEMS = ACELine.split()
    if  ACE_ITEMS[1] in protocols_list:
      if len(ACE_ITEMS) == 5:
        if ACE_ITEMS[2] == 'host' or ACE_ITEMS[2] == 'any':
          p = re.sub(r'(.*)(\bany\b|\bhost \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (.*)',r'\1\3 \2',ACELine)
          print(ACELine)
          print(p)
        elif ACE_ITEMS[4] == 'host' or ACE_ITEMS[4] == 'any':  
          p = re.sub(r'(.*) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (\bany\b|\bhost \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',r'\1 \3 \2',ACELine)
          print(ACELine)
          print(p)
      elif len(ACE_ITEMS) == 6: 
        if ACE_ITEMS[2] == 'host' and ACE_ITEMS[4] == 'host':
          p = re.sub(r'(.*) (host \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (host \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',r'\1 \3 \2',ACELine)
          print(ACELine)
          print(p)
        elif ACE_ITEMS[2] == 'host' and bool(re.search(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',ACE_ITEMS[4])) and bool(re.search(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',ACE_ITEMS[5])):
          p = re.sub(r'(.*)(\bhost \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (.*)',r'\1\3 \2',ACELine)
          print(ACELine)
          print(p)
        elif ACE_ITEMS[4] == 'host' and bool(re.search(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',ACE_ITEMS[2])) and bool(re.search(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',ACE_ITEMS[3])):
          p = re.sub(r'(.*) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (\bhost \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',r'\1 \3 \2',ACELine)          
          print(ACELine)
          print(p)
        else:
          p = re.sub(r'(.*) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',r'\1 \3 \2',ACELine)
          print(ACELine)
          print(p)
      else:
        print(f'ERROR: ACE items length must be either 5 or 6 : {ACELine}')
    else:
      print(f'ERROR: Protocols not supported : {ACE_ITEMS[1]}') 
      exit()

  return ReversedACE


if __name__ == "__main__":
 aces = [
 'permit ip any host 10.22.122.161',
 'permit ip host 10.11.198.18 any',
 'permit ip host 10.22.122.161 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7',
 'permit ip host 10.22.122.161 host 10.22.122.255',
 'permit ip any host 10.22.122.255',
 'permit ip 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7 host 10.22.122.255',
 'permit ip any 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7',
 'permit ip 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7 any',
 'permit ip any 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15',
 'permit tcp any 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15',
 'permit tcp 172.16.150.208 0.0.0.15 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7'
 ]
 for ace in aces:
   ChangeACESrcDst(ace)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
import re
host_ip_pos = re.search(r'host\s\d*.\d*.\d*.\d*', str1).span()
print(host_ip_pos)
(10, 28)

new_str = str1[:host_ip_pos[0]] + str1[host_ip_pos[1]+1:] + ' ' + str1[host_ip_pos[0]: host_ip_pos[1]]
print(new_str)
permit ip 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7 host 10.22.122.161
```

Comment: Would you please clarify what do `str1[host_ip_pos[1]+1:]` and `str1[host_ip_pos[0]: host_ip_pos[1]]` mean ?

Comment: `host_ip_pos` contains the position (start and end index) of the regex pattern in the string. `host_ip_pos[0] = 10`  and `host_ip_pos[1]= 28` starting and ending positions respectively.  So when using positions I am slicing the string.  `str1[host_ip_pos[1]+1:] means str1[29:] i.e 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7' So I am simply swapping the data based on the positions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using regex and f-strings like this:

```py
import re

def swap_ips(text: str) -> str:
    ip = r'\d+\.\d+.\d+.\d+'
    ip_pattern = f'(host {ip}) ({ip}) ({ip})'
    match = re.search(ip_pattern, text)
    host, mid, dest = match.groups()

    new_order = f'{mid} {dest} {host}'
    return text[:match.start()] + new_order + text[match.end():]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = 'permit ip host 10.22.122.161 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7'
    print(swap_ips(text))
```

output:

```
permit ip 192.168.150.16 0.0.0.7 host 10.22.122.161
```

Comment: Would you please explain more about `(text: str) -> str` since I need to modify the regex  to match other patterns

Comment: `: str` part is a type annotation. It's mainly to help IDEs and editors for autocompleting attribute and methods. Here it means `swap_ips` function will take a `str` and return a `str`. You could safely remove them and replace the function signature with `def swap_ips(text):` of course

Comment: I've generalized my solution for other protocols and actions, please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Is there more efficient implementation, so I can swap Source and Destinations from all variants of the Input list?